# How to show loading icon on Add to Cart Button in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a loading symbol on Add to Cart button when user clicks it. Currently in my site, when user clicks the button, it do nothing for 2-4 seconds and shows view cart button.

I want to show some loading or spinning icon during these 4 seconds. Is it possible? can someone guide me

Link: http://www.myeatable.com/cnc-ongole/

Comment: You have also some problem in this theme. After refreshing cart become zero. And check in plugin folder assets have ajax-loader@2x.gif this image or not

Answer (score 6):

I have a better solution, there is no need to append some image to the button.

WooCommerce provides a class 'loading'. Simply append this class to Add to Cart button and that's it.

```
$( '.add_to_cart_button' ).on( 'click', function(){
   $(this).addClass('loading');
});
```

And as soon as the product is added to cart you can use the removeClass function to remove the loader like

```
 $(this).removeClass('loading');
```

And for adding a WooCommerce Loader to a particular section you can use these WooCommerce functions

```
block( $( 'div.summary.entry-summary' ) );
unblock( $( 'div.summary.entry-summary' ) );
```

These two function block's and unblocks a particular section by passing the specific id or class.

```
var is_blocked = function( $node ) {
    return $node.is( '.processing' ) || $node.parents( '.processing' ).length;
};

var block = function( $node ) {
    if ( ! is_blocked( $node ) ) {
        $node.addClass( 'processing' ).block( {
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
                background: '#fff',
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        } );
    }
};

var unblock = function( $node ) {
    $node.removeClass( 'processing' ).unblock();
};
```

Comment: I think you are saying to add 'loader' class, not 'loading'. Right?
Also, it only shows the spinner. I want the little transparent overlay box also. Any idea, which class will be used for that?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: is this code is working ?

Comment: Works great for me, thanks so much!

Comment: how do I know htat the product is loading or not?

Comment: @loganYoung , how can i add this code to snippet plugin in Wordpress ?

Comment: This is working for me without processing class, Thanks @LoganYoung

Answer (score 3):

For the loading image on add to cart i might suggest to write a code in your js which loads on that page.

```
jQuery('a.add_to_cart_button').click(function(){jQuery(this).append('<img src="http://smallenvelop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Preloader_3.gif" width="20px" height="20px"/>')});
```

The link to image for loading is for example your can replace it with the one you want to.

Further more before apply the code in a file try to add it in from the browser console.

Comment: how can i add this code to my snippet in wordpress , or where i can i add this jquery code to my add to cart process , please advice